# Simple_form: how to change input's wrapper's class?(not the wrapper_html effect on)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a problem when using simple_form and Bootstrap 3. About the input's wrapper tag. Show codes below:

**view code**(with haml)

```
= simple_form_for @refer_email_form, url: create_refer_message_path, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f|
  = f.input :to, label_html: { class: "col-sm-2" }
  = f.input :subject, label_html: { class: "col-sm-2" }
```

**config/simple_form_bootstrap.rb**

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.input_class = "form-control"

  config.wrappers :bootstrap, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label, class: "control-label"
    # b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: "col-sm-6" do |ba|
    b.wrapper tag: 'div' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

 config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap
```

I just want to use the "Horizontal form" by default

**the generated html**

```
...
\<div class="form-group string optional refer_email_form_to">
  <label class="string optional control-label col-sm-2" for="refer_email_form_to">To</label>
  <div>
    <input class="string optional form-control" id="refer_email_form_to"   name="refer_email_form[to]" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
...
```

What I want is to change the `<div>`'s class which just wrap the `<input>` element, something like this:

```
...
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input class="string optional form-control" id="refer_email_form_to"   name="refer_email_form[to]" type="text">
<div>
...
```

I've read the README from simple_form's github page, and googled for this problem, I know I can achieve this by adding `b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: "col-sm-6" do |ba|` to the **config/simple_form_bootstrap.rb** file, but the real problem is that I may use different class for the div, maybe `col-sm-9` in other form. And I tried the `input_html`, `wrapper_html` in the view, but the `wrapper_html` effects on the first `<div class="form-group">`, and `input_html` only effects on the `<input>` element

Is there any way to change the `<input>`'s wrapper `<div>` dynamically in the view ?

Answer (score 21):

Change

```
b.wrapper tag: 'div' do |ba|
```

to

```
b.wrapper :my_wrapper, tag: 'div' do |ba|
```

Set up the input field as follows

```
= f.input :to, label_html: { class: "col-sm-2" }, wrapper: :bootstrap, my_wrapper_html: { class: "css-class-name-goes-here" }
```

The generated HTML is

```
<div class="form-group string optional refer_email_form_to">
  <label class="string optional control-label col-sm-2" for="refer_email_form_to">To</label>
  <div class="css-class-name-goes-here">
    <input class="string optional form-control" id="refer_email_form_to"   name="refer_email_form[to]" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Notes**

1. I have to explicitly specify the “bootstrap” wrapper to make it work. The following setting doesn't seem to take effect `config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap`
2. It doesn't work when I name the wrapper `bootstrap` as you do. The setting works when I use a different name such as `bootstrap_x`. This might be my local problem so this is just for your information in case you run into the same problem.
3. If you're curious where all the above comes from, check out simple_form README file, it's in the "The wrappers API" section.

Comment: Thanks Hoa. I did read the **wrappers API**, I think this is a way for the problem, and I'll try that.